# Maven intherit false on specific executions

Tags: maven, inheritance

I have a multimudule maven project which I'd like to use as with the maven enforcer plugin. I set up multiple executions, checking for things at different phases of the build.

The project is structured so that the parent module's version is inherited to the child modules. The parent module has a parent module defined as well, let's call it grandparent.

One of these executions is to check whether the parent pom is a snapshot version and fail if it is.

The problem is that I can't build a snapshot of the child modules, because that would mean that the parent module is a snapshot as well, which fails the above-mentioned enforcer rule.

What I need is to keep the enforcer rule for the parent module, but skip this and only this rule on the child modules.

What I was trying to do is this:

in the grandparent.pom I have declared the enforcer rules like this:

```
...
<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>only-on-parent</id>
    <rules>...</rules>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>all-modules</id>
    <rules>...</rules>
  </execution>
</execution>
...
```

in the parent.pom:

```
...
<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>only-on-parent</id>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
  </execution>
</execution>
...
```

This does nothing, the rule still gets applied to the child modules.
if I do this on the parent.pom:

```
...
<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<inherited>false</inherited>
...
```

than none of the rules gets applied, neither the ones declared in `all-modules`.

Any tips to solve the problem without having to go in and skip the execution on all children manually?